# How can I convert a String into ASCII and then back in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell

I am a beginner in Haskell (started this morning) and am trying to make a function to encrypt a string of characters by converting it to ASCII, adding a specified integer to the ASCII and then converting back into a String. I think I have correctly done this for a single character but I am stuck when it comes to the full String:

```
import Data.Char

encodeChar :: Char -> Int -> Char
encodeChar 'x' y = chr ((ord 'x') + y)

encode :: String -> Int -> String
encode (x : xs) y = chr ((ord (x : xs)) + y)
```

Comment: You'll find some good information in the haskell tag's "info" section, one of which will point you to hoogle which you could use to answer your question

Comment: Why do you think you have done it correctly for a single char? Have you tested it? You should be able to test it fairly easily by running `ghci nameofyourfile.hs` and then typing, say, `encodeChar 'a' 5`

Comment: Immibis, I have tested it and it seems to work. However, I get an error when just applying the map function like Alec suggested above.  *edit

Comment: *edit - the code loaded without error when I opened the hs file but the function did not work itself. I apologise for the confusion, as I said before I only started coding this morning.

Comment: Oops! I'm not surprised my comment didn't work - I'm just surprised someone up voted it! ```encode s y = map (`encodeChar` y) s``` should though.

Comment: @SyedAhamed I don't think you have because your `encodeChar` only works for the letter x

Comment: @immibis could you please explain why my code only works for the letter x? How can I generalise this? And how could I apply this to a string?

Comment: @SyedAhamed Well you wrote `encodeChar 'x' y = ...stuff...` which means that the stuff applies when the first argument is `'x'` (literally the letter x) and the second argument is `y` (which is a variable so it could be anything). Probably you meant `x` instead of `'x'`

Comment: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), If you have a function for an item, there usually be the way to apply function on collection of items. In this case it is [map](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.4/base-4.9.1.0/Prelude.html#v:map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To encode a string, an option is to proceed recursively. First, we choose how to encode the empty list `[]`. Then, assuming `encode xs y` does its job, we define what `encode (x:xs) y` should be.

After some reflection we can see that `encode (x:xs) y` should be a string whose first character is the encoding of `x` using `y`, i.e. `encodeChar x y`, while the rest of the string (the tail) is the encoding of `xs` using `y`, i.e. the result of the recursive call.

We then obtain:

```
encode :: String -> Int -> String
encode []       y = []
encode (x : xs) y = encodeChar x y : encode xs y
```

This kind of recursion is so common that there's a library function, `map`, which can perform it for us.

`map f [x1, .., xn]` returns `[f x1, .., f xn]`. Hence, we can map the `encodeChar` function over the whole string.

```
encode :: String -> Int -> String
encode xs y = map (\x -> encodeChar x y) xs
-- or, using more advanced functions
encode xs y = map (flip encodeChar y) xs
```